# Selenium phantomjs webdriver hangs on click

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to navigate through pages by clicking next button. It works for first two three pages, after that it just hangs while clicking.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("path to phantomjs",desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("http://www.zappos.com/product/review/7391917/page/1/start/5")

print driver.current_url
for i in range(5):
    print i
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[class='top-pagination'] a[class*='next']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print driver.current_url
```

The following is the output which shows the click happens for first few pages and the resulting URL change. But it hangs after first few clicks indefinitely.

```
http://www.zappos.com/product/review/7391917/page/1/start/5
0
http://www.zappos.com/product/review/7391917/page/2/start/5
1
http://www.zappos.com/product/review/7391917/page/3/start/5
2
```

Any idea on why it happens ?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error, the snippet works fine. Maybe add some more information so that we could find what is the problem ? Where does your program hangs exactly ? In `driver.find_element...` ? Have you try to print the code_source page before ?

Comment: yeah it happens on that line...i use selenium version 2.53.6 and phantomjs version 2.1.1.....and these kind of hanging issue happens only on this site for me... i  haven't faced these issues with other sites.... yeah the page source looks fine...

Comment: can you update your phantomjs and selenium version ?

Comment: PhantomJS 1.9.7, selenium==2.53.6. On Linux. You can maybe try with another browser ?

Comment: i ll try with phantomjs 1.9.7...i want it to run as headless...so phantomjs is the only option as of now

Comment: @VivekSrinivasan did downgrading from 2.1.1 to 1.9.7 work for you?  i just upgraded from 1.9.1 to 2.1.1 due to a different problem and am now hitting this (another site, not zappos).